# storcli cannot add diks to RAID10 - 255 Start Migrate not possible

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, storage, raid10, storcli

list of Disks:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                   Sp Type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0     8 UGood -  931.000 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB U  -
252:1     9 UGood -  931.000 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB U  -
252:4    10 Onln  0  931.000 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB U  -
252:5    11 Onln  0  931.000 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB U  -
252:6    12 Onln  0  931.000 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB U  -
252:7    13 Onln  0  931.000 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB U  -
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

my command to add the new disks including the error:
(The current setup is already RAID10)

```
./storcli64 /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid10 option=add drives=252:0,252:1

CLI Version = 007.2103.0000.0000 Dec 08, 2021
Operating system = VMkernel 7.0.0
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = None

Detailed Status :
===============

------------------------------------------------------
VD Operation Status ErrCd ErrMsg
------------------------------------------------------
 0 Migrate   Failed   255 Start Migrate not possible.
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Bit more detail please, what are you trying to do here? and why are you using consumer disks?

Comment: how do you mean more details? what details?
As stated in the question I want to "add the new disks". I posted the list of disks and the command used. everything should be clear so far. If there was more output I would have posted it. But maybe you can tell me how to get more output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding RAID-10 by adding disks is not possible on MegaRAID controllers. As such, it is not possible to expand *any* array that includes more than one span, please see the [supporting documentation](https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161503168/how-to-expand-an-array-on-megaraid-controllers-adding-drives-to-) from Broadcom. The only option you have is make a backup, delete the volume and then create a new one and restore.